# How I can capture previous and current URL to a hidden form field

Tags: form

I need to create a hidden form field and populate the previous and current URL can someone tell me how I can do that in Craft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of Craft 3,

```
<input type="hidden" name="referrerUrl" value="{{ craft.app.request.getReferrer()" />

<input type="hidden" name="currentUrl" value="{{ craft.app.request.getAbsoluteUrl() }}" />
```

You can see other methods off of the `web/Request` object you can use here: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html